# Java code to check if a pcollection is empty

Tags: apache-beam

I am trying to write a pipeline to insert/update/delete mysql table based on the pubsub messages.While inserting into a particular table, I will have to check if the data exists in other table and do the insert only when the data is available in the other table

I will have to stop the insertion process , when there is no data in the other table(PCollection).

PCollection recordCount= windowedMatchedCollection.apply(Combine.globally(new CountElements()).withoutDefaults());

This piece of line does not seem to help. Any inputs on this please

Answer (score 0):

It's a little unclear exactly what you're trying to do, but this should be achievable with counting elements. For example, suppose you have

```
# A PCollection of (table, new_row) KVs.
new_data = ...

# A PCollection of (table, old_row) KVs.
old_data = ...
```

You could then do

```
rows_per_old_table = old_data | beam.CombinePerKey(
    beam.combiners. CountCombineFn())
```

and use this to filter out your data with a [side input](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#side-inputs).

```
def maybe_filter_row(table_and_row, old_table_count):
  # table_and_row comes from the PCollection new_data
  # old_table_count is the side input as a Map
  table = table_and_row[0]
  if old_table_count.get(table) > 0:
    yield table_and_row

new_data_to_update = new_data | beam.FlatMap(
    maybe_filter_row,
    old_table_count=beam.pvalue.AsMap(rows_per_old_table))
```

Now your `new_data_to_update` will contain only that data for tables that had a non-zero number of rows in old_data.

If you're trying to do this in a streaming fashion, everything would have to be windowed, including `old_data`, and it would filter out only those things that have data in that same window. You could instead do something like

```
# Create a PCollection containing the set of tables in new_data, per window.
tables_to_consider = (
    new_data
    | beam.GroupByKey()
    | beam.MapTuple(lambda table, rows: table))

rows_per_old_table = tables_to_consider | beam.ParDo(
    SomeDoFnLookingUpCurrentSizeOfEachTable())

# Continue as before.
```

Comment: Appreciate your reply here! I do have the windowing logic applied and once the data is windowed I am not able to use the count on it. I am trying using Java SDK and would you be able to help me further?

Comment: If you have Winding applied the count will be per-window. SomeDoFnLookingUpCurrentSizeOfEachTable could be used to avoid this. The side input link above should allow you to select "java" to see how this would be expressed in that language.